# (aus)drucken oder (aus)drucken lassen?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

When I need to print something out of a printer I am always puzzled:

If I go to the printer and push the button myself, since I don't process the page myself, but the machine does, I am thinking of using:

> (aus)drucken lassen -> Ich lasse diesen Bericht (aus)drucken.

Then simultaneously I think: whatever happens in the machine is irrelevant. I stand up and go there and nobody helps/does that for me (I do that and the machine does not count as helper) and I use:

> (aus)drucken -> Ich drucke diesen Bericht aus.

**Which one is correct?**

Comment: Julius Caesar used to write entire passages using constructions like *Caesar fecit pontem* (Caesar built a bridge) even though you can be sure his hands didn't touch a single brick or log. Just think of yourself as an important personality and write the simpler form :-)

Comment: this is very much related to daily chores: _Ich muss noch Wäsche waschen_, although your washing machine will likely do the job for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beides ist richtig, selbst wenn Du einen modernen Computerdrucker benutzt, bei dem Du nicht aufstehen und einen Knopf drücken musst.

Viel gebräuchlicher ist es, zu sagen "Ich drucke diesen Text" als "Ich lasse diesen Text ausdrucken". Man sagt auch nicht "Ich lasse dieses Hühnchen einfrieren" (von meiner Tiefkühltruhe), sondern "Ich friere dieses Hühnchen ein." Das *lassen* wird eher benutzt, wenn man sich der Hilfe einer anderen Person bedient und die Aufmerksamkeit darauf lenken will ("Ich lasse mir den Bart stutzen").

Der Automatisierungsgrad spielt wohl eine Rolle. Man sagt jedenfalls nicht "Ich lasse mir ein Loch bohren" (von der Bohrmaschine) sondern "Ich bohr mir ein Loch" und man sagt auch "Ich fahr nach Rügen", auch wenn es der Lokführer oder der Chauffeur tut, aber bei Letzterem könnte man auch sagen "Ich lasse mich nach Rügen fahren" um zu betonen, dass man selbst keine Anstrengung dabei hat.

Answer (score 2):

In normal office use I would prefer

> Ich drucke das aus.

in nearly all circumstances, the only exception being if you just give a hint to a secretary or team assistant in which case

> Ich lasse das (nochmals) ausdrucken.

reflects the delegation aspect. (Of course, this may also be used for faking importance like to suggest you have a secretary.)

The combination with *lassen* is also appropriate, when you require an external company, like a printer service (due to needing special paper or stapling), as in

> Wir haben die Broschüre drucken lassen.